# How do you avoid viewport collapse of a centered background image?

Tags: html, css

I am using a layout where I have a centered title/logo image at the top and it connects with the background image which is being repeated vertically.

The problem is that the background only stays centered as long as the viewport is sufficiently wide enough. When I decrease its width below the width of the background image, the background image is no longer centered and is just drawn starting from the left so it no longer connects to the logo image.

I drew that picture just for your personal amusement.

Comment: Yes, the background is funny, thanks!

Comment: I like making it look like he's dancing by shrinking the window down below 600px and swiping it back and forth. Makes me laugh. Seriously though, if I understand what you're asking, you want something outside the div to stay fixed relative to the background image inside the div?

Comment: I'm in Firefox 3.6 and I don't see the background layout issues you are talking about: I figure I'm just not understanding it. Could you provide a couple of screen shots of working/non-working layouts?

Comment: I *think* what he means is if you shrink the browser window small enough, you'll see the body drawn outside the div no longer lines up with the body inside the div, but I'm waiting for clarification.

Comment: It's precisely what kinakuta said. When you make it small enough, it will no longer align because the background would have to get drawn outside the boundaries of the viewport on the left side to achieve the appropriate centering. Apparently HTML/CSS don't work that way, though.

Comment: Here is the screenshot requested by Femi: http://213.251.177.42/misc/background-problem/screenshot.png

Answer (score 1):

is what you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/FZAMX/ ?

Comment: Hmm no, you aren't addressing the problem of the graphics no longer lining up in that case and I definitely do not want the image to get stretched in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-width` on body to be at least equal to your image with borders. In this test case that is 642px;

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that but it didn't change anything about the background. The background is still drawn off-center in that case - I am not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting min-width on `html` to be the min-width of the image? I tried that on your first link in Chrome and it seemed to work. I set min-width to 680px.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using a body background-image after all, making a 100% min-height div which always extends to the bottom is much easier. Here's what I came up with: http://213.251.177.42/misc/background-problem/container.html